# Accessing certain elements in an Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So I have the following struct I created:

```
struct _I_TypeInstructions {
    const char *instructionName;
    char *opcode;
} I_TypeInstructions[] = { { "lw", "100011" }, { "sw", "101011" }, { "beq",
        "000100" } };
typedef struct _I_TypeInstructions I_TypeInstructionsStruct;
```

If I have a new instructionName and I want to check if it is in the I_TypeInstructionsStruct how do I iterate through just the *instructionName part of the struct above. For example the function I want to write would look something like

```
bool checkIfInstructionIsI_Type(char *instructionName) {
    // somehow iterate through instructionNames in the struct above
    // checking if parameter char *instructionName in this method is equal to 
    // "lw" "sw" "beq" but skipping over the binary numbers.
}
```

Comment: I assume there will be more than three instructions in your list. A lot more than three. And performance is crucial. I suggest to go for a hash table or a binary three instead of a list.

Comment: There will only be 6, the assembler I am creating will not be supporting that many instructions.

Comment: You don't know how to iterate an array of structures, but you are writing an assembler? Talk about deep end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching a list of structs is rather straight forward:

```
bool checkIfInstructionIsI_Type(char *instructionName) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<NumInstructions; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(I_TypeInstructions[i].instructionName, instructionName) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    if (strcmp(instructions[i].instructionName, instructionName) == 0)
    {
        printf("Match found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally more useful to return the actual element that matches your string. It's the same amount of work anyway.

Add an empty element to the end of your array and then you have a end marker.

```
typedef struct _I_TypeInstructions {
    const char *instructionName;
    char *opcode;
} I_TypeInstructionsStruct;

I_TypeInstructionsStruct I_TypeInstructions[] = {
{ "lw",  "100011" },
{ "sw",  "101011" },
{ "beq", "000100" },
{ 0,     0}
};

I_TypeInstructionsStruct *find_instruction(char *name)
{
    I_TypeInstructionsStruct *i ;
    for (i = I_TypeInstructions ; i->instructionName ; i++)
        if (!strcmp(i->instructionName,name)) return i ;
    return 0 ;
    }
```